# How to fix IndexError from numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import mmread
from scipy import linalg


A = mmread('bcspwr02.mtx')
A =np.transpose(A)+A+np.identity(A.shape[0])

#A = np.array([[20, 18, 1], [2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 1]])

def get_b(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    b = np.ones(n)
    return b

def Jacobi(A, b, numIter):

    n = A.shape[0]
    x=np.zeros(n)
    x0 = np.zeros(n)

    for numItr in range(numIter):
        print("Iteration "+ str(numItr) + ": " + str(x))
        for i in range(len(A)):
            temp = 0
            for j in range(len(A)):
                if i != j:
                    temp = x0[j] * A[i][j]
            x[i] = float((b[i] - temp) / A[i][i])
        else:
            x0 = x.copy()


numIter = 4
Jacobi(A, get_b(A), numIter)
```

Result:

```
Iteration 0: [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0.]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/cxf/Desktop/test.py", line 36, in <module>
    Jacobi(A, get_b(A), numIter)

  File "/Users/cxf/Desktop/test.py", line 29, in Jacobi
    temp = x0[j] * A[i][j]

File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 193, in __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: The key to problem is the **numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py** in the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly does `mmread` return?

```
A = mmread('bcspwr02.mtx')
A =np.transpose(A)+A+np.identity(A.shape[0])
```

The docs say "Dense or sparse matrix depending on the matrix format in the Matrix Market file."

Let's experiment with a sparse matrix:

```
In [52]: A = sparse.coo_matrix([[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]])
In [53]: A
Out[53]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [54]: A.A
Out[54]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])

In [58]: A1 = np.transpose(A)+A+np.identity(A.shape[0])
In [59]: A1
Out[59]: 
matrix([[3., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 2.],
        [1., 2., 1.]])
In [60]: A1[0]
Out[60]: matrix([[3., 0., 1.]])    # shape (1,3)
In [61]: A1[0][0]
Out[61]: matrix([[3., 0., 1.]])    # still (1,3)
In [62]: A1[0][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-62-c6007014201d>", line 1, in <module>
    A1[0][1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 193, in __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

If `A` is `coo` matrix, then the transpose expression creates a `np.matrix`.  `A1[i][j]` indexing does not work the same as for regular numpy array.  Instead you need to use the safe `A1[i,j]` syntax.

```
In [63]: A1[0,1]
Out[63]: 0.0
```

Note that the traceback tells me the error is in the `defmatrix` file.  I should have read your traceback more carefully.  The nature of the problem was hidden in plain sight!

## initial

Evidently, in

```
x0[j] * A[i][j]
```

either `j` or `i` is too large.  Why - we/you have to look at how they are set, and what the shape of `x0` and `A` are.

Try to understand the error before asking how to fix it.

---

In the commented line `A` is (3,3), so `n=3`.  Then `x0` will be (3,) shape.  `i` and `j` iterate over `range(3)`.  With those shapes

```
x0[j] * A[i][j]
x0[j] * A[i,j]    # better
```

should work.

But the error says one of the arrays has shape (1,?) or (1,).

You need to check the array shapes.  Don't just assume the shapes are right; when there's an error, you must verify.

---